# Pass multiple ID's to JS function

Tags: javascript, html

My goal in this code is to show specific div tags when the link is clicked and hide all other div tags. I keep rewriting it in different ways but can't seem to get it working properly.

JavaScript below...

```
    function show(id1, id2, id3, id4)
    {
    document.getElementById(id1).style.visibility="visible";
    document.getElementById(id2).style.visibility="hidden";
    document.getElementById(id3).style.visibility="hidden";
    document.getElementById(id4).style.visibility="hidden";
    }
```

HTML below...

```
<a href='#home' onclick="show('home', 'info', 'payment', 'contact')">Home</a>
<a href='#info' onclick="show('info', 'home','payment','contact')">Information</a>
<a href='#payment' onclick="show('payment', 'info', 'home','contact')">Payment</a>
<a href='#contact' onclick="show('contact', 'info', 'payment','home')">Contact</a>


<div id="home">Content</div>
<div id="info">Content</div>
<div id="payment">Content</div>
<div id="content">Content</div>
```

Comment: And your question is... ?

Comment: Consider using `class` to select all elements that needs to be operated.

Comment: @Tushar what's that? They cannot get it working. That's sad. There is no question there though.

Comment: You just made a spelling error. contact and content are different IDs.

Comment: @Quentin got it right.

Comment: My purpose of putting this here is because it doesn't work. So my question would be what have I done wrong. I post here to learn things I don't know that we'll...

Comment: Well*. The spelling error isn't in my actual code. I just made a mistake when posting it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not working properly because you are passing `contact` in your function instead of `content`.

Consider using `display:none` instead of `visibility` because if you use `visibility` your content will be hidden but it will leave a space behind:

```js
function show(id1, id2, id3, id4)
    {
    document.getElementById(id1).style.display="block";
    document.getElementById(id2).style.display="none";
    document.getElementById(id3).style.display="none";
    document.getElementById(id4).style.display="none";
    }
```

```html
<a href='#home' onclick="show('home', 'info', 'payment', 'contact')">Home</a>
<a href='#info' onclick="show('info', 'home','payment','contact')">Information</a>
<a href='#payment' onclick="show('payment', 'info', 'home','contact')">Payment</a>
<a href='#contact' onclick="show('contact', 'info', 'payment','home')">Contact</a>


<div id="home">Home Content</div>
<div id="info">Info Content</div>
<div id="payment">Pay Content</div>
<div id="contact">Con Content</div>
```

Comment: Please explain why you downvote, your comment can help me improve my answer

Answer (score 0):

If this is your html:

```
<div id="home" class="singleVisible" onclick="disableOthers(this)">Content #1</div>
<div id="info" class="singleVisible" onclick="disableOthers(this)">Content #2</div>
<div id="payment" class="singleVisible" onclick="disableOthers(this)">Content #3</div>
<div id="content" class="singleVisible" onclick="disableOthers(this)">Content #4</div>
```

Then this could be your script:

```
function disableOthers(e) {
    var all = document.getElementsByClassName('singleVisible');

    for(var i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
        // First make all of the elements with the same class hidden.
        if (all[i] !== this) {
            all[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }

        // Then make the clicked element visible.
        e.style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
}
```

While I feel that it's important that people learn JavaScript this is the sort of thing that jQuery DOES really help with. The 'onclick' attributes above are not recommended for multiple reasons but if you're going to want to remove those and replace them with actual event handler calls in JavaScript then you ALSO are probably going to want to make sure you support older (IE8, not THAT old) browsers as well. Check this out:

http://www.anujgakhar.com/2013/05/22/cross-browser-event-handling-in-javascript/

In any case, the JQuery version is as simple as removing those onclick attributes and using this script instead:

```
<div id="home" class="singleVisible">Content #1</div>
<div id="info" class="singleVisible">Content #2</div>
<div id="payment" class="singleVisible">Content #3</div>
<div id="content" class="singleVisible">Content #4</div>

<script>
    $('.singleVisible').click(function() {
        $('.singleVisible').hide();
        $(this).show();
    });
</script>
```

Also, note that best practice (if you can) is to have a parent container and attach the event to that instead. Otherwise in both examples I've given you're attaching four event handlers in each case. It's as simple as wrapping the links in a parent div and doing something like this:

```
<div id="parent">
     <div id="home" class="singleVisible">Content #1</div>
     <div id="info" class="singleVisible">Content #2</div>
     <div id="payment" class="singleVisible">Content #3</div>
     <div id="content" class="singleVisible">Content #4</div>
</div>

<script>
    $('#parent').on('click', '.singleVisible', function() {
         $('.singleVisible').hide();
         $(this).show();
    });
</script>
```

Have fun! =)

Answer (score -1):

Give all your div elements a class. On click:

1. hide all of them by using

   getElementsByClassName

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

2. make the particular div visible by its id

Doing these kind of DOM manipulations is very easy with jQuery.